# Visual Studio IDE Types and Members selectboxes lost

Tags: visual-studio

The two dropdown list that display the Types and Members on the open document, right on top of the source editor is lost.

How can I re-enable them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> (either the language choice e.g C#, or All Languages)  and make sure that on the Display section Navigation Bar is checked.